# How to show that there is no $3\times3$ real matrix $A$ such that $A^2+I=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Question: show that there is no $3\times3$ real matrix $A$ such that $A^2+I=0$?

Is it because: 
$$\det(A^2)=\det(-I)\\
\implies \det(A)\det(A)=-1\\
\implies \det(A)=-i$$
How to continue?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your argument. Note that it nowhere uses the size of $A$, so your proof holds for any $n\times n$ matrix. In fact, it generalizes the statement that $x^2 + 1=0$ has no real solution, since that's the equation you get when $n=1$. Nice.

Comment: Note that it uses the fact that $n$ is odd when computing $det(-I)$

Comment: Note that such an $A$ does exist when $n=2$.

Comment: Since $A$ is a real matrix, then you are done. You get a contradiction

Comment: According to your argument $|A|$ should be $\pm i$

Comment: @MPW It doesn't hold for any $n\times n$ because $\det(I_n)=(-1)^n$.

Comment: Your argument works for $3\times3$ matrices, and generalizes to $n\times n$ when $n$ is odd. (Although your last line should be $\det(A) = \pm i$, not $\det(A) = -i$.) But when $n$ is even, $\det(-I) = (-1)^n \det(I) = 1$, not $-1$. And indeed there are solutions to $A^2+I=0$ when $n$ is even.

Comment: @npisinp Your comment is at best misleading. There are real matrices with non real eigenvalues.

Comment: @user130217: Ah, yes of course, you're right. I was surprised that the size didn't enter into it, but I was wrong about that. I guess each row of $I$ carries the scalar factor of $-1$, so they collectively factor out of the determinant as $(-1)^n$.  My bad. Still, the idea of the proof is clever.

Comment: @GitGud: Yes, thanks, see my previous comment. Guess I wasn't thinking clearly.

Comment: @GitGud How come? Can you give me an example? If a real matrix can have a determinant in $\mathbb{C}$ than I resign.

Comment: @npisinp You're right, nevermind.

Comment: @GitGud: I think you misunderstood npisinp. He is correct. If a matrix has entries from a field $\mathbb F$, then its determinant also lies in $\mathbb F$. Here the field is $\mathbb R$, sot it's not possible that the determinant is $\pm i$, right?

Comment: @MPW Yes, thanks, see my previous comment. Guess I wasn't thinking clearly. ^_^

Comment: @MPW To make it explicit for a $2\times 2$ matrix, we simply take a rotation around the origin by $90^\circ$. That is the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. Its square is $-I$, multiplication by minus one. For even $n$ we can make an $n\times n$ matrix that works by repeating $2\times 2$ blocks like this along the main diagonal. These matrices have no real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every real $3 \times 3$ matrix, being of odd size, has a real eigenvalue since the characteristic polynomial is of odd degree.  If $A^2 + I = 0$, and $A\mathbf v = \lambda \mathbf v$ with $\mathbf v \ne 0$, then $0 = (A^2 + I) \mathbf v = (\lambda^2 + 1) \mathbf v \Rightarrow \lambda^2 + 1 = 0$.  Applying this notion to a real eigenvalue of $A$ leads to an immediate contradiction, since no real $\lambda$ satisfies $\lambda^2 + 1 = 0$.  Hence, no real $3 \times 3$, or indeed $n \times n$ for $n$ odd, matrix $A$ satisfies $A^2 + I = 0$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal:  thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

OP, I like your proof *way* better than ^^.  Intuitively it seems like you want to show that it implies existence of solution to $X^2 + 1 = 0$ in $\Bbb{R}$.

You had:
$$
\det(A^2)=\det(-I)\\
\implies \det(A)\det(A)=-1\\
$$

What you have now is, assuming that there is such a $3\times 3$ then there exists a real number $X = \det(A)$ such that $X^2 = -1$.  But you know that's not true from studying algebra & polynomials, so *contradiction*!